# Custom iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I've implemented an iterator like this

```
template <typename GridT, 
          typename GridPtr,
          typename GridRef,
          template <typename> class ShapeT>
class GridIterator
{
public:
    typedef GridIterator<GridT, GridPtr, GridRef, ShapeT> Iterator;

    // Iterator traits - typedefs and types required to be STL compliant
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t            difference_type;
    typedef typename GridT::Element   value_type;
    typedef typename GridT::Element*  pointer;
    typedef typename GridT::Element&  reference;
    typedef size_t                    size_type;
    typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;

    GridIterator(GridT& grid,
                 ShapeT<typename GridT::Resolution> shape,
                 Index iterStartIndex);

    ~GridIterator();

    Iterator& operator++();
    Iterator  operator++(int);

    typename GridT::Element& operator*();
    typename GridT::Element* operator->();

    bool operator==(const GridIterator& rhs) const;
    bool operator!=(const GridIterator& rhs) const;


private:

    GridT& grid_;
    ShapeT<typename GridT::Resolution> shape_;
    Index iterIndex_;
    Index iterIndexEnd_;

};
```

It works fine with the std::generate and std::find, but when I use it with std::max_element I get his error:

> main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’: main.cpp:105:16:
>   error: ‘iter’ was not declared in this scope In file included from
>   /usr/include/c++/4.6/algorithm:63:0,
>                    from ./grid/Map_Grid.h:11,
>                    from main.cpp:4: /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h: In function ‘_FIter
>   std::max_element(_FIter, _FIter) [with _FIter =
>   Map::GridIterator, Map::Grid*,
>   Map::Grid&, Map::Rectangle>]’: main.cpp:102:53:
>   instantiated from here /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:6243:4:
>   error: use of deleted function ‘Map::GridIterator, Map::Grid*, Map::Grid&,
>   Map::Rectangle>& Map::GridIterator,
>   Map::Grid*, Map::Grid&,
>   Map::Rectangle>::operator=(const Map::GridIterator, Map::Grid*, Map::Grid&,
>   Map::Rectangle>&)’ In file included from ./grid/Map_Grid.h:8:0,
>                    from main.cpp:4: ./grid/Map_GridIterator.h:17:8: error: ‘Map::GridIterator, Map::Grid*, Map::Grid&, Map::Rectangle>&
>   Map::GridIterator, Map::Grid*,
>   Map::Grid&, Map::Rectangle>::operator=(const
>   Map::GridIterator, Map::Grid*,
>   Map::Grid&, Map::Rectangle>&)’ is implicitly deleted
>   because the default definition would be ill-formed:
>   ./grid/Map_GridIterator.h:17:8: error: non-static reference member
>   ‘Map::Grid& Map::GridIterator,
>   Map::Grid*, Map::Grid&,
>   Map::Rectangle>::grid_’, can’t use default assignment operator

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It sounds impossible to answer you without the implementation. The error log only suggests that an illegal copy assignment was performed.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment operator (that `max_element` appears to require) is not default-generated for your iterator because of the reference member

```
GridT& grid_;
```

...which cannot be changed to reference a different `GridT` object. One easy way to fix this is to hold the grid by pointer instead.